# returning a button from a function VB.net

Tags: vb.net, function, button

In my program I have to reference different dynamically created buttons and they are stored in an array of records. Depending on what FieldShow is equal to, one of three FlowLayoutPanels are visible, which contain the buttons.

```
Private Function GetFields(i As Integer) As LoadingTemplate
        Dim TempFields As LoadingTemplate
        If FieldShow = 0 Then
            TempFields.B = Study(i)
        ElseIf FieldShow = 1 Then
            TempFields.B = Task(i)
        ElseIf FieldShow = 2 Then
            TempFields.B = Note(i)
        End If
        Return TempFields
End Function
```

TempFields.B.RefBtn, if used here, then shows the button that is being returned, But if elsewhere I put

```
GetFields(x).B.RefBtn
```

with an appropriate value for X, it sometimes doesn't return things. Is there an easier way of doing this? 
Thanks, 
Henry

Comment: For what purpose are you referencing the button?  If it's to handle the click event, in the form load handler use the Addhandler statement to set each button to the same handler.  You cast sender as button and then you can reference the name of the button and the parent container of the button.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing is disposed of (e.g. when the window closes). Btw, it's a valid question, why you are storing button references. Usually you don't want to handle UI stuff in your code (except it is necessary), but update the UI through data binding.